# Не инициализируется первоначальное состояние owl carousel - ошибка TypeError: el.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, css, slider, owl-carousel, transform

Есть новостной слайдер скомпонованный из двух взаимодействующих `owl-carousel`, который работает по переключению как стрелок, так и по названиям пунктов меню в правом блоке.

Есть 2 бага:
1 - не инициализируется первоначальное состояние пункта меню, бьет ошибку в функции **carouselInitialized**

> Uncaught TypeError: el.find is not a function

Делал по принципу [первой версии](http://for-dle.ru/owl/demos/sync.html), но там в *callback функции* `afterInit` все работало исправно..

2 - в какой-то момент переключений слайдов возникает аналогичная ошибка и слайды с пунктами меню в итоге сбиваются.

Как это исправить? [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lecht29/1)

**Сам код**

```js
var sync1 = $("#sync1");
var sync2 = $("#sync2");

sync1.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
  singleItem: true,
  pagination: false,
  onChanged: syncPosition,
  responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
  nav: true,
  navText: ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>"],
  animateOut: "fadeOut"
});

sync2.owlCarousel({
  items: 4,
  pagination: false,
  responsiveRefreshRate: 100,
  //afterInit : carouselInitialized
  onDragged: carouselInitialized
  //onInitialized: carouselInitialized
});

function carouselInitialized(el) {
  el.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
}

function syncPosition(el) {
  var current = el.relatedTarget.current() - 1;
  $("#sync2")
    .find(".owl-item")
    .removeClass("synced")
    .eq(current)
    .addClass("synced");

}

$("#sync2").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var i = $(this).index() - 5;
  sync1.trigger('to.owl.carousel', i);
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel-wrapper {
  padding: 12px 12px 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#sync1-wrapper,
#sync2-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
}

#sync1 .item {
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

#sync1 .item>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#sync2 .owl-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#sync2 .owl-item {
  width: 100% !important;
  float: none;
}

#sync2 .item {
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#sync2 .synced .item {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
  border-color: #0c88e7;
  color: #0596D5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="owl-carousel-wrapper">
  <div id="sync1-wrapper">
    <div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i0.wp.com/bookmaker-ratings.com.ua/ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/FK-Atalanta.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="desc">Футбольный комментатор «Матч ТВ», спортивный журналист, главный инсайдер российского футбола и эксперт «Рейтинга Букмекеров»…</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i2.wp.com/bookmaker-ratings.com.ua/ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/2-222.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="desc">Футбольный журналист, эксперт «Рейтинга Букмекеров» Артур Петросьян составил экспресс из ставок на матчи 3-го тура…</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i1.wp.com/bookmaker-ratings.com.ua/ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Liga-CHempionov2-2.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="desc">«Рейтинг Букмекеров» подготовил для вас пять самых интересных событий для ставок на спорт в период с 21 по 27 октября. Лига…</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i2.wp.com/bookmaker-ratings.com.ua/ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/rb-lejptsig-verner-e1569586830809.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="desc">Бывший полузащитник московского «Спартака», футбольный эксперт «Рейтинга Букмекеров» и БК «Лига Ставок» Евгений Ловчев дал…</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><div id="sync2-wrapper">
    <div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="item">Назван фаворит матча “Лион” - “Зенит” в первом туре Лиги</div>
      <div class="item">«William Hill» и другие британские букмекеры несут грандиозные убытки</div>
      <div class="item">Открыт прием ставок на тур, в котором сборная России выйдет на Евро-2020</div>
      <div class="item">«Бетсити» стал официальным букмекером «Монако» в России</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: как воспроизвести баги? Здесь все вроде бы норм работает

Comment: @Дмытрык  - первый баг - при инициализации сразу, не подсвечивается активный пункт меню
второй - если перещелкать пункты туда-сюда вверх/вниз раз 10, на каком-то этапе выбивает ошибку. в демо все видно

Comment: Почему у вас `carouselInitialized` стоит на событии `onDragged`? Чего вы хотите этим добиться?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko потому что иначе пункты меню совсем не работают, а на событии `onDragged` по крайней мере отрабатывают, но где-то чего-то не хватает..

Answer (score 4):

Надо было использовать событие `onInitialized`. Первый аргумент - это событие, а не элемент.

Событие `onDragged` срабатывает, когда вы пытаетесь сделать drag&drop элементов карусели, поэтому при быстром нажатии, у вас иногда *в какой-то момент переключений слайдов возникает аналогичная ошибка и слайды с пунктами меню в итоге сбиваются.*, т.е. происходит событие `ondrag`.

```js
var sync1 = $("#sync1");
var sync2 = $("#sync2");

sync1.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
  singleItem: true,
  pagination: false,
  onChanged: syncPosition,
  responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
  nav: true,
  navText: ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left' aria-hidden='true'></i>", "<i class='fa fa-chevron-right' aria-hidden='true'></i>"],
  animateOut: "fadeOut"
});

sync2.owlCarousel({
  items: 4,
  pagination: false,
  responsiveRefreshRate: 100,
  onInitialized: carouselInitialized
});

function carouselInitialized(e) {
  // e - это событие, а не элемент карусели
  $(e.currentTarget).find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("synced");
}

function syncPosition(el) {
  var current = el.relatedTarget.current() - 1;
  $("#sync2")
    .find(".owl-item")
    .removeClass("synced")
    .eq(current)
    .addClass("synced");

}

$("#sync2").on("click", ".owl-item", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var i = $(this).index() - 5;
  sync1.trigger('to.owl.carousel', i);
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel-wrapper {
  padding: 12px 12px 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#sync1-wrapper,
#sync2-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
}

#sync1 .item {
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

#sync1 .item>img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#sync2 .owl-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#sync2 .owl-item {
  width: 100% !important;
  float: none;
}

#sync2 .item {
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#sync2 .synced .item {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
  border-color: #0c88e7;
  color: #0596D5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="owl-carousel-wrapper">
  <div id="sync1-wrapper">
    <div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i0.wp.com/bookmaker-ratings.com.ua/ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/FK-Atalanta.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="desc">Футбольный комментатор «Матч ТВ», спортивный журналист, главный инсайдер российского футбола и эксперт «Рейтинга Букмекеров»…</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i2.wp.com/bookmaker-ratings.com.ua/ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/2-222.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="desc">Футбольный журналист, эксперт «Рейтинга Букмекеров» Артур Петросьян составил экспресс из ставок на матчи 3-го тура…</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i1.wp.com/bookmaker-ratings.com.ua/ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Liga-CHempionov2-2.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="desc">«Рейтинг Букмекеров» подготовил для вас пять самых интересных событий для ставок на спорт в период с 21 по 27 октября. Лига…</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://i2.wp.com/bookmaker-ratings.com.ua/ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/rb-lejptsig-verner-e1569586830809.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="desc">Бывший полузащитник московского «Спартака», футбольный эксперт «Рейтинга Букмекеров» и БК «Лига Ставок» Евгений Ловчев дал…</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sync2-wrapper">
    <div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="item">Назван фаворит матча “Лион” - “Зенит” в первом туре Лиги</div>
      <div class="item">«William Hill» и другие британские букмекеры несут грандиозные убытки</div>
      <div class="item">Открыт прием ставок на тур, в котором сборная России выйдет на Евро-2020</div>
      <div class="item">«Бетсити» стал официальным букмекером «Монако» в России</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```